# Android espresso test pass locally but fails on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, automation, android-espresso, firebase-test-lab

I have issue with android espresso test.
Test pass locally but fail on FTL. It's simple test

`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.text_supercategory_name), withText("Air conditioners"))).
check(matches(withText("Air conditioners")));`

this test pass locally. On FTL I have error:

`android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: blablabla:id/text_product_verdict and with text: is "Air conditioners")`

I’m not understand whay I see ID which not used in my test `id/text_product_verdict` … and this ID from another activity …
Activity for test is correct

`@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<HomeActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(HomeActivity.class);`

I checked the video of the failed test on FTL and see a lot of notifications on emulator
[img from FTL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubTzt.png)

I decide that the problem was a sticky notification from Google Hangouts and try run my test with `--no-auto-google-login` flag. But have the same results. With `onView(withText("Air conditioners")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));` test pass on FTL.

Is anyone can help with with issue?

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well. It seems Firebase Test Lab does not recognize the **id** at `withId(R.id.text_supercategory_name)` in some devices. We can use **res-name** instead.

Check out the view hierarchy in the log and grab the res-name in there with `onView(withResourceName("res-name")).perform(click());`

```
// change res-name to buttonPanel, button3, button2, or button1
+---->ScrollView{id=16908757, res-name=buttonPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1008, height=217, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=1507.0, child-count=1}
|
+----->ButtonBarLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1008, height=217, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4}
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=16908315, res-name=button3, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>Space{id=16909293, res-name=spacer, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=429, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=42.0, y=203.0}
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=16908314, res-name=button2, visibility=VISIBLE, width=271, height=189, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=471.0, y=14.0, text=Cancel, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
+------>AppCompatButton{id=16908313, res-name=button1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=224, height=189, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=742.0, y=14.0, text=OK, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue also when using espresso. Then I using [Barista](https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista) for espresso wrapper. It's helping me to choose using R.id.name or R.string.name or "name" as the selector. 
Here click example from their GitHub :

```
clickOn(R.id.button);
clickOn(R.string.button_text);
clickOn("Next");
```

Answer (score 0):

The ID(integer value) of the view is dynamically changed in each build. It works when when the same build of the app and test apk are upload to firebase. However when different builds are uploaded, it fails.